# Java : Reading CSV to Linked List (with a twist)

Tags: java, database, csv, linked-list

I am a newbie to programming and was learning Java myself from [Core Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132354764) .

The book mentioned a few lines about reading `csv` files in Java and storing its contents into a `data-structure` .

So while trawling the internet , I came across the following problem :

> - There is a school which has the following actors : *Faculty , Staff and Students*
> - **Faculty** has the following attributes : *Name , Phone Number , E-Mail ID Address , Department , No. of Research Papers*
> - **Students** has the following attributes : *Name , Phone Number , E-Mail ID , Address , Roll No. , GPA*
> - **Staff** has the following attributes : *Name , Phone Number , E-Mail ID , Address , Department , Salary*
> - Now , the all this data is stored in a single `csv` file in the following manner :

```
Student,Harry Potter,9999999,hp@hogwarts.magic,Hogsmeade Street,1,4.0

Staff,Argus Filch,888888,arg@mrsnorris.com,Hogwarts,Cleaning,5000

Faculty,Snape,555555,snape@snivellus.com,Hogwarts,Potions,40000

.
.
.
.
```

> - Now , I need to read the data from the cs file , in Java , and store it into a linked list such in the following order : *Faculty Records followed by Staff Records followed by Student Records*

**My Code :**

The code that I have written till now is :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class readCSV {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
  {
   
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("CSV.csv"));
    scanner.useDelimiter(",");
     
    
    while (scanner.hasNext())
    {
        // Read the tokens and store them into a Linked List 
    }
     
    
    scanner.close();
  }
}
```

**My Problem :**

Can someone help me out ? I do not want to use any library to parse the csv and also want to make my own linked list from scratch -- it will be a good practice

`My main problem is to read from csv and store the data into a linked list . An illustrative code snippet would go a long way`

<sup>**Disclaimer**: This is not a homework question . I am self-learning Java</sup>

Comment: So what is the question? How to make a linked list?

Comment: by creating your own linked List you mean you don't want to use the java.util.List..?

Comment: BTW the way.  The problem you found includes some bad design but front in the question.  A sane implementation probably not conflate the (separate) concepts of Faculty/Student/Staff by storing them all in the same CSV file.  For one thing, the 'columns' in the input data mean different things depending on the 'type' of the row.

Comment: Hi @Bubletan , My main problem is to read from csv and store the data into a linked list . An illustrative code snippet would go a long way ...

Comment: @All , why the downvote ? I can increase the exposition if required ...

Comment: @Paul , yes that is probably bad but my main problem is to read from csv and store the data into a linked list . An illustrative code snippet would go a long way ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse the file with something like this:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("CSV.csv"));
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    if (line.isEmpty()) {
        continue;
    }
    String[] parts = line.split(",");
    String name = parts[1];
    String number = parts[2];
    String email = parts[3];
    String address = parts[4];
    switch (parts[0]) {
    case "Faculty":
        String department = parts[5];
        String papers = parts[6];
        // add to list
        break;
    case "Student":
        String roll = parts[5];
        String gpa = parts[6];
        // add to list
        break;
    case "Staff":
        String department = parts[5];
        String salary = parts[6];
        // add to list
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For linked lists I'd suggest reading one of Robert Sedgewick's *Algorithm* books.  (Implementing a linked list itself is not going to be too hard if a) you know some Java and b) you know how linked lists work.)  I expect there are plenty of example on the web, too.

Having written your own linked list implementation (for learning): throw it away and don't use it in real programs.  Seriously.  The existing library implementations are going to be way better; writing real-world collections libraries is a serious undertaking.

Parsing CSV is more complicated than is sounds if your data (text) can contain commas and quotes that are *not* CSV delimiters (which is usually true in real data).

However a naive implementation might be:

- Open the file using a `LineNumberReader`.
- Call `readLine()` in a loop until you get back null (no more lines).
- Split each line read with `line.split(",")`.
- Process each line's fields.

Comment: You should also ask yourself why you want, specifically, a linked list - rather than some other kind of list implementation.  (I don't think a linked list would be my first choice, in the context of what you are trying to do.)

Comment: Hi @Paul , my main problem is to read from csv and store the data into a linked list . An illustrative code snippet would go a long way ... thanks in advance :)